# Manually scrolling through list

Tags: flash, apache-flex, list, flash-builder

I need to manually handle the scrolling through a list using the arrows keys, while i successfully handled the changing the selection through the items, if the list is bigger than its display and needs to use a scroller, then that scroller wont wscroll with the selected item.

This is what i have for now:

```
        function completionListUpDown(direction:Boolean):void{
            if(direction){
                if(popUp.completionList.dataProvider.length == (popUp.completionList.selectedIndex + 1)){
                    popUp.completionList.selectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else{
                    popUp.completionList.selectedIndex += 1;
                }

            }
            else{
                if(0 == popUp.completionList.selectedIndex){
                    popUp.completionList.selectedIndex = popUp.completionList.dataProvider.length - 1;
                }
                else{
                    popUp.completionList.selectedIndex -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

This scrolls trough the items like a charm, but if there is a vertical scroller, then that scroller wont be scrolled. How do i make that scroller scroll?

Comment: Witch List class ? from Flex (mx package) ? from Sparks ? A third-party lib ?

Comment: sparks, but i allready solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL, nevermind i just found the solution, just use ensureIndexIsVisible(selectedIndex)

```
        function completionListUpDown(direction:Boolean):void{
            if(direction){
                if(popUp.completionList.dataProvider.length == (popUp.completionList.selectedIndex + 1)){
                    popUp.completionList.selectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else{
                    popUp.completionList.selectedIndex += 1;
                }

            }
            else{
                if(0 == popUp.completionList.selectedIndex){
                    popUp.completionList.selectedIndex = popUp.completionList.dataProvider.length - 1;
                }
                else{
                    popUp.completionList.selectedIndex -= 1;
                }
            }
            popUp.completionList.ensureIndexIsVisible(popUp.completionList.selectedIndex);
        }
```